# \begin{align} giving messed up alignment + bad box error

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am having a problem with this. In texStudio ,it's not even running, and in sharelatex, it runs but the alignment is messed up...

```
\begin{align}
 k &= 1\\
 && T(n) = 4T(n-1)-4T(n-2)\\
 k &= 2 \\
 && T(n) &= 4[4T(n-2)-4T(n-3)]-4T(n-2)\\
 &= 16T(n-2) -16T(n-3) - 4T(n-2)\\
 \end{align*} $
```

I'm getting a badness 1000 error and a "misplaced alignment tab character &"

Comment: I think you should give us a complete code. Why for example have you a `$` after `align*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There several problems here. (1) you're using `\begin{align}` but closing with `\end{align*}.` They're two different environments; you must chose one (the stared version doesn't number the equations). (2) There's a `$` at the end. You should enclose the whole `align` (or `align*`) environment within `\[` and `\]`. (3) I'm not sure how you want to align these equations. If you use one `&`, there will be two "columns" aligned at the center on the place where the `&` is. But if you use two `&`'s, that'll tell LaTeX to create three columns, and so on.

Anyway, this is working code fragment and the result.

```
\[
\begin{align*} 
 k &= 1\\
 && T(n) = 4T(n-1)-4T(n-2)\\
 k &= 2 \\
 && T(n) &= 4[4T(n-2)-4T(n-3)]-4T(n-2)\\
 &= 16T(n-2) -16T(n-3) - 4T(n-2)\\
\end{align*}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: "... should *not* include the whole `align` ..."  if this is to be nested, then `aligned` should be used if no numbers are wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 k    &= 1 \\
 T(n) &= 4T(n-1)-4T(n-2) \\
 k    &= 2 \\
 T(n) &= 4[4T(n-2)-4T(n-3)]-4T(n-2)\\
      &= 16T(n-2) -16T(n-3) - 4T(n-2)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]